# Get work item store from Tfs using powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs

How do I get a WorkItemStore from TFS using powershell?

I've tried the following:

```
function get-tfs {

  param(
        [string] $ServerName = "http://MyServer:8080/tfs"
  )

  begin{}

  process
  {
        [psobject] $tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)
        return $tfs
  }
  end{}
}     

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll")
```

The above code executes fine and I have a value for $tfs.

Then I do this:

```
   $wis = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
```

But $wis is null.  Same thing if I do this instead:

```
   $wis = $tfs.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
```

Also, if I do this, powershell says it cannot find assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client' even though it just found it and loaded it a second ago:
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client

I don't understand why it found the assembly then suddenly can't find it anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this works for me:

```
function get-tfs
{
    param([string] $ServerName = "http://myserver:8080/tfs")

    $binpath   = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0"
    Add-Type -path "$binpath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll"
    Add-Type -Path "$binpath\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"

    $creds = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.UICredentialsProvider
    $teamProjectCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection $ServerName,$creds

    $ws = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
    return $ws
}
```

Comment: For me, the return value is null.  Everything is fine up until the second-last line ($teamProjectCollection | gm gives me the appropriate members)    But the $ws= line doesn't work for me.  $ws | gm gives null reference exception ("no object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet"). I'm pulling my hair out now.

Comment: Try adding /DefaultCollection to your URI.  I'm using *.visualstudio.com and needed to do that before it worked, but I'm not sure if it's needed for a local server.

Comment: Doesn't help.  Am I supposed to get something when I go to http://server:port/tfs/DefaultCollection?   I get 404 for that, but when I go to http://server:port/tfs, i get the web interface for the last project I visited in DefaultCollection.

Comment: I guess I had something in my profile.ps1 interfering with your code, and possibly also with the original code I posted.  I tried deleting everything from profile.ps1 except your function, and now it works... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having issues getting WorkItemStore with Powershell attempts.  Needed it to clone a PBI with tasks cloned also.  Found this .Net soln.  Worked like a charm!  Actually had to add a try catch around a History null exception, but after that, bam!

https://github.com/DanielMeixner/WorkItemDeepCopy/

Comment: please consider copying the part that is useful to your answer. Otherwise it won't be useful in the future. Thanks