# Get GA date from the release items in TFS using powershell

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-sdk

Can you please tell me how to fetch the GA Date or Test Pass Start time columns data from tfs using powershell.

In which class i can find these properties so i can fetch data.

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking for the `WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem().Fields["Fieldname"]` in the [TFS Client Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx) or [the similar functionality in the rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items):  depending on your TFS version and source platform.

Since Powershell can call into .NET Objects you can use the TFS Client Object Model. OR you can use the Invoke-RestMethod to interact with the REST APIs.

If you're looking for a more powershell aligned method, [look at the TFSCmdLets](https://github.com/igoravl/tfscmdlets). [It returns a TFS Client Object Model instance](https://github.com/igoravl/tfscmdlets/wiki/Get-TfsWorkItem) of the WorkItem class, so the first example code will provide more information on what to expect.

Comment: I am new to powershell .I tried WorkItemStore.GetWorkItem().Fields["Fieldname"] but in fields there is no columns with GA Date and Test pass Start

Comment: For more details on how to access the work item store, query for specific work items etc, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25431364/736079.

Comment: As for which underlying field name you need, depends on the process template. These are non-standard fields, so I can't tell what field name you're after specifically. Grab the Work Item Type Definition XML to see what the underlying field is. Use `witadmin exportwitd` from the Vsiual Studio Command Line to export the work item type to get the detailed information.